# Activity log for specific azure resource

Tags: python, azure, activitylog

I am trying to query the activity logs of a specific azure resource. However, I am not sure how to do it. I only found base code on the internet that can only filter up to resource group level.

```
    from azure.mgmt.monitor import MonitorManagementClient
    import datetime

    # Get a client for Monitor
    credentials = connectSP() # Custom function to get credentials
    client = MonitorManagementClient(
        credentials,
        sub_id
    )


    # Generate query here
    today = datetime.datetime.now().date()
    filter = "eventTimestamp ge {}".format(today)
    select = ",".join([
        "eventTimestamp",
        "eventName",
        "operationName",
        "resourceGroupName",
    ])


    # Grab activity logs
    activity_logs = client.activity_logs.list(
        filter=filter,
        select=select
    )

    # Print the logs
    for log in activity_logs:
        print(" ".join([
            str(log.event_timestamp),
            str(log.resource_group_name),
            log.event_name.localized_value,
            log.operation_name.localized_value
    ]))
```

I tried to filter it by resource_id attribute but is met with this error:

```
Code: BadRequest
Message: The filter property: resource_id is not supported.
```

Is it possible to narrow down the scope to just a resource? Also is there any documentation on how to modify the filter query? I just found the basic ones in the Microsoft documentation. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-monitor/azure.mgmt.monitor.v2015_04_01.operations.activitylogsoperations?view=azure-python

Comment: Try filtering by resourceUri.     `filter = "eventTimestamp ge {} and resourceUri eq {}".format(today, resourceUri)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Code: BadRequest
> Message: The filter property: resource_id is not supported.

The error shows that ResourceID is not supported in the **$filter** argument.

The **`$filter`** has restrictions refer [MS-Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-mgmt-monitor/azure.mgmt.monitor.v2015_04_01.operations.activitylogsoperations?view=azure-python) for detailed information.

The **$filter** argument is very restricted and allows only the following patterns.

1. **List events for a resource group:**

```
$filter=eventTimestamp ge '<Start Date Time>' and eventTimestamp le '<End time>' and resourceGroupName eq '<Resource Group Name>'.
```

2. **List events for resource:**

```
$filter=eventTimestamp ge '<Start Date Time>' and eventTimestamp le '<End Date Time>' and resourceUri eq '<Resource URI>'.
```

3. **List events for a subscription in a time range:**

```
$filter=eventTimestamp ge '<Start Date Time>' and eventTimestamp le '<End Date Time>'.
```

4. **List events for a resource provider:**

```
$filter=eventTimestamp ge '<Start Date time>' and eventTimestamp le '<End Date Time>' and resourceProvider eq 'resourceProviderName'.
```

5. **List events for a correlation Id:**

```
$filter=eventTimestamp ge '<Start Date Time>' and eventTimestamp le '<End Date Time>' and correlationId eq 'correlationID'.`
```

If you need to filter specific resource, you can use **Resource URI**. Filter through resource group Use **ResourceGroupName**. Resource ID is not supported in the $filter.

The sample code I followed.

```py
Sub_Base_Url = f"https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{Your_Subscription_Id}/providers/microsoft.insights/eventtypes/management/values?api-version=2015-04-01&"
# in filter you can use either Resource Group Name or Resource URI
filter = f"$filter=eventTimestamp ge '{Start_Date_time}' and eventTimestamp le '{End_Date_Time}' and resourceGroupName eq '{Your_Resource_Group}'"
print(filter)

Sub_Base_Url = Sub_Base_Url + filter

headers = {
    "Authorization": 'Bearer ' + credential.token["access_token"]
}

res = requests.get(Sub_Base_Url, headers=headers)
output = res.json()
```